# UILabel + touchDown

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Is it possible to implement touchdown for UILabel?

Answer (score 5):

`UILabel` is a subclass of `UIView`, which is itself a subclass of `UIResponder`; therefore, it’s definitely possible to make a label that responds to touches. Just make a new subclass of `UILabel` and implement the following method(s):

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

So, if you wanted something to happen when touches started, you’d do it in `-touchesBegan:withEvent:`.

If creating a new subclass is too heavy-handed for you, then I’d suggest doing as @JustSid suggests and using a `UIButton` for the task.

Comment: As long as you're not targeting pre-3.2 you can also just add a UIGestureRecognizer to the view...

Answer (score 5):

`UILabel` has `userInterationEnabled` set to NO by default.

```
[label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[label addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchedLabel:)]];


- (void)touchedLabel:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
NSLog(((UILabel*)gesture.view).text);
]
```

Comment: It does the job and should definitely be considered as the best answer. Beware of the memory leak however: the UITapGestureRecognizer should be autoreleased.

Comment: TapGestureRecognizer only calls the method on TouchUp, not TouchDown. If you want to detect TouchDown you should set a delegate for the GestureRecognizer and implement the gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: method.

Answer (score -3):

No, thats not possible. But you could use an UIButton with UIButtonTypeCustom as type for this task.

Comment: That is not correct. Check Pedro's answer for the best solution.