# Change label color with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a label with UITapGestureRecognizer and longgestureRecognizer:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("labelPressed:"))
let longgestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("longLabelPressed:"))
label.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
label.addGestureRecognizer(longgestureRecognizer)
```

I want to change color like in UIButton, when it pressed:

```
func longLabelPressed(recognizer:UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        if let label = recognizer.view as? UILabel {
            if recognizer.state == .Began {
                label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            }

            if recognizer.state == .Ended {
                label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }



        }
    }
```

But how to detect tap end event ?

```
func labelPressed(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let label = recognizer.view as? UILabel {

        }

    }
```

My goal is create label like UIButton with touch events.

Comment: what is the issue with your code ?

Comment: If that is your goal, why are you not using a button instead?

Comment: because i have this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652981/cell-swipe-event-and-button-touch-inside-event

Comment: so i need to replace buttons to labels :( or if you find solution better...

Comment: i think even if u use tap gesture recogniser, it will mess with the table tap gesture . IT is always better to use UIButtons

Comment: Maybe the solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4158149/3222713

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UserInteractionEnabled for label is by default false** . so if you are using its label outlet then enable it from (XIB/ storyboard)

Now to make label same like button using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`
and then you event called successfully but you write label color change code in `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` so its take some time(default time) to detect touch event. `recognizer.state == .Began`   so change minimum time for long pressGesture

```
longgestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.001
```

using that `recognizer.state == .Began`  will call quickly .

Comment: thanks, this is a good solution, but in this case label convert to UIButton and i have this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652981/cell-swipe-event-and-button-touch-inside-event/34656301?noredirect=1#comment57059595_34656301

Answer (score 3):

Make a new subclass of UILabel and implement this :

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    textColor = UIColor.blue
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    textColor = UIColor.white
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    textColor = UIColor.black
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    textColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Don't forget to set :

**Objective-C**

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

**Swift 4**

```
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Add the custom class to your label in your xib and enjoy :)

**Reference : [UILabel + touchDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158099/uilabel-touchdown/4158149#4158149)**

Answer (score 1):

Like the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/userInteractionEnabled) mentoined you should enable unser interaction.

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("labelPressed:"))
let longgestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("longLabelPressed:"))

label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

label.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
label.addGestureRecognizer(longgestureRecognizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You should set `userInteractionEnabled` property on the label to `true` (as someone mentioned earlier)
2. Using `UITapGestureRecognizer` will only give you information when the gesture is finished. If you want to know when it begins I would suggest using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and setting its `minimumPressDuration` property to 0.